# Django SUM Query?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a query akin to the following:

```sql
SELECT SUM(name) FROM table WHERE name IS NULL
```

How does that `SUM` translate into a `QuerySet` in Django? i.e. What operation `xyz` does it translate to, in something like `MyModel.objects.xyz()`?

Comment: if you have an advanced usecase you might need conditional expressions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Update: The following incorporates the ISNULL aspect of the original query:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

ModelName.objects.filter(field_name__isnull=True).aggregate(Sum('field_name'))
# returns {'field_name__sum': 1000} for example
```

You're looking for the Sum aggregation function, which works as follows:

```
ModelName.objects.aggregate(Sum('field_name'))
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum

Comment: `result = ModelName.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('field_name'))['total']`

Answer (score 1):

You can also alias the returned value:

```py
MyModel.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('field_1'))
```

which returns a dictionary such as `{'total': 12345}`.

If you need to filter the values to be summed over, another way is to use the `filter=` parameter of the `Sum` object via the `Q` object. The following returns the total of `field_1` values where the corresponding `field_2` values are null, i.e. the equivalent of the SQL query `SELECT SUM(field_1) FROM table WHERE field_2 IS NULL`.

```py
from django.db.models import Q, Sum
MyModel.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('field_1', filter=Q(field_2__isnull=True)))
```

You can also use a dictionary to store the sum and unpack as keyword arguments when passed to `aggregate()`.

```py
dct = {'total': Sum('field_1', filter=Q(field_2__isnull=True))}
MyModel.objects.aggregate(**dct)
```

both of which return a dictionary such as `{'total': 1234}`.