# Django: Calculate the Sum of the column values through query

Tags: python, django, sum, aggregate, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class ItemPrice(models.Model):
     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
     # ...
```

I tried this to calculate the sum of `price` in this queryset:

```
items = ItemPrice.objects.all().annotate(Sum('price'))
```

What's wrong in this query? or is there any other way to calculate the Sum of `price` column?

I know this can be done by using for loop on queryset but i need an elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django SUM Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481279/django-sum-query)

Answer (score 313, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`aggregate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset)

```
from django.db.models import Sum

ItemPrice.objects.aggregate(Sum('price'))
# returns {'price__sum': 1000} for example
```

Comment: How can i get total count whose price=5000 ?

Comment: Remember returns dictionary not float/integer e.g. `{'price__sum':1000}` . Can get float/integer with `yourdict['price__sum']`

Answer (score 65):

Use `.aggregate(Sum('column'))['column__sum']` reefer my example below

```
sum = Sale.objects.filter(type='Flour').aggregate(Sum('column'))['column__sum']
```

Comment: I am getting an error : 'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable

Answer (score 54):

Annotate adds a field to results:

```
>> Order.objects.annotate(total_price=Sum('price'))
<QuerySet [<Order: L-555>, <Order: L-222>]>

>> orders.first().total_price
Decimal('340.00')
```

Aggregate returns a dict with asked result:

```
>> Order.objects.aggregate(total_price=Sum('price'))
{'total_price': Decimal('1260.00')}
```

Comment: I appreciate you showing how to specify the `key` to store the sum `value` into.

Answer (score 11):

Using *cProfile profiler*, I find that in my development environment, it is more efficient (faster) to sum the values of a list than to aggregate using `Sum()`.
eg:

```
sum_a = sum([item.column for item in queryset]) # Definitely takes more memory.
sum_b = queryset.aggregate(Sum('column')).get('column__sum') # Takes about 20% more time.
```

I tested this in different contexts and it seems like using `aggregate` takes always longer to produce the same result. Although I suspect there might be advantages memory-wise to use it instead of summing a list.

Comment: Alternatively, use a generator expression instead of a list: `sum_a = sum(item.column for item in queryset)`. The only difference is the removed `[]`s. This saves the memory space for calculating the entire list before `sum()` iterates over it.

Comment: getting an error : 'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable

Answer (score 8):

Previous answers are pretty well, also, you may get that total with a line of vanilla code...

```
items = ItemPrice.objects.all()
total_price = sum(items.values_list('price', flat=True))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also get the sum this way:

```
def total_sale(self):
    total = Sale.objects.aggregate(TOTAL = Sum('amount'))['TOTAL']
    return total
```

Replace the 'amount' with the column name from your model you want to calculate the sum of and replace 'Sale' with your model name.

Comment: Please don't forget to import Sum:  from django.db.models import Sum

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [aggregate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate) and [Sum()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#sum) to calculate the sum of `price` column as shown below. *The query with [all()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#all) is equivalent to the query without [all()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#all) as shown below:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

print(ItemPrice.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('price')))
print(ItemPrice.objects.aggregate(Sum('price')))
```

Then, these dictionaries below are outputted on console:

```
{'price__sum': Decimal('150.00')}
{'price__sum': Decimal('150.00')}
```

And, you can change the default key `price__sum` to `priceSum` for **price** column as shown below:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum
                                        # ↓ Here
print(ItemPrice.objects.all().aggregate(priceSum=Sum('price')))
print(ItemPrice.objects.aggregate(priceSum=Sum('price')))
                                  # ↑ Here
```

Then, the default key is changed as shown below:

```
{'priceSum': Decimal('150.00')}
{'priceSum': Decimal('150.00')}
```