# Django Access Sum of Child Class Attributes

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner working on a school fees management software with Django.
My Problem is Below:

I have two models, Student and Family:

```
from django.db import models

--snip--
class Family(models.Model):
    father = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mother = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    total_fees = students.fees.aggregate(models.Sum('fees'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.father+" " +self.mother

class Student(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='students', default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField('Date Of Birth')
    fees = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    email= models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Im trying to get all the total fees of a family by adding up the fees of all the students in the family: 
`total_fees = students.fees.aggregate(models.Sum('fees'))`

I used the solution stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616343/django-calculate-the-sum-of-the-column-values-through-query).

but i get this error when i try to migrate:

```
File "/home/my_username/mysite/students_app/models.py", line 34, in Family
    total_fees = students.fees.aggregate(models.Sum('fees'))
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'fees'
```

What is the correct way to get the total fees for a family?


Thanks!

PS: This is my first question, please tell me how I can improve my questions :)

Comment: What is "students" in students.fees

Comment: I am trying to use the 'related_name' attribute.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642613/what-is-related-name-used-for-in-django EDIT: I did not understand related name properly. Answer below solves my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't consider "Total Fees" being a field of either Family or Student. I would opt for a method in the Family model that queries for the fees for all the students in that family.

First step is import the Sum aggregation function from django.db.models into your models file:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
```

Then, define the function in your Family class that does the aggregation. Note that [aggregate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) returns a dictionary of name-value pairs. So as you had your query previously set up, it would've returned something like: `{'fees__sum': 100000}`.

So you need to access the value in the dictionary by that generated key, like:

```
Student.objects.filter(family=self).aggregate(Sum('fees'))['fees__sum']
```

Putting it all together:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

class Family(models.Model):
    father = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mother = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.father+" " +self.mother

    def get_students_total_fees(self):
        return Student.objects.filter(family=self).aggregate(Sum('fees'))['fees__sum']
```

With this, you could then have a Family object and get the fee total:

```
family_object = Family.objects.get(Id=1)
family_students_fees_total = family_object.get_students_total_fees()
```

Comment: EDIT: This is throwing me an error!: `AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'Filter' `Sorry for the delay

Comment: Hmm, I did notice I wrote "object" instead of "objects" in my query, which I have corrected in the answer. Try replacing that.

Comment: Yes, that was one of the errors, I corrected and it still doesn't work, however, I made some changes myself and the error may be occurring because of my changes; this solution works when I try it for another model. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Isn't the code wrong because the `Student` model is not defined(It is called before  it is defined?) in `return Student.objects.filter(family=self).aggregate(Sum('fees'))`?
Or am I incorrect? I will read Docs.

Comment: Tested my code and updated the answer. And no, order of definition in the model shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thank you. The error was because of the dictionary, it works now!

Comment: Also, i was typing capital 'Filter'. Correct is 'filter'