# Very slow django with "large" database (< 1M rows)

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, render

I'm trying to build an app with django. When I work with a small database (around 10k rows), the app works perfectly. However, in some views, I need to calculate some data of my classes, so I need to call all of my database. It is very slow (more than 30s), and according to [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), most part of the time is consumed by CPU.

Here's an example of a (very) simplified code I try to launch:

```py
def test_view(request):
    queryset_articles = Articles.objects.all()
    total_count = sum([a.words_count for a in queryset_articles])
    response = 'Total words : ' + str(count)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

How should I do to get a reasonable waiting time? I think about doing another table, which I would update frequently with these historical stats, then call them directly in my view.

Thank you,

Pierre

Comment: "_call all of my database_"?? That is generally not adviced and it may even _crash_ your server if there is too much data. Is the only thing you want there a _sum_ of some field? If so this question will probably give you your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616343/django-calculate-the-sum-of-the-column-values-through-query

Answer (score 1):

Try [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/). It can provide a small to noticeable increase in time since it uses a database query to count.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total_count = Articles.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('words_count'))
print(total_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should check if the Django Debug Toolbar itself is not the reason for this waiting time (its documentation explains the problem and provides some solutions [here](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tips.html#performance-considerations)).

Then, did you try to use [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/) ? This could optimize your code:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Articles.objects.aggregate(Sum('words_count'))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried Django Toolbar after I noticed the site was very slow, so it is not the cause of the slowness

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answers, this view is now a lot faster!
However, I got some views to calculate average with different filters, like this:

```py
        hours_of_weekday = [Article.objects.filter(
            date__hour=k,
            date__week_day=weekday_num,
            type__in=categories).aggregate(Avg('count'))['count__avg'] for k in range(0, 24)]
```

Which is still very slow with this... Any idea except making a table dedicated to these values?