# Sum total value for all items

Tags: django

I have a query set that contains a number of transactions for a particular product.

`transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(product__product_name_id = item.id)`

Within this queryset contains a number of fields.

```
product
amount
price
transaction_date
```

I need to calculate the totals of the values in the amount fields.

The current query set is returning  2 `amounts` from 2 `transactions'

Would it be sensible to loop through each transaction and add it to a list of something? or is there a better way?

```
list = []
for item in transactions:
   amount = item.amount
   list.append(amount)
```

Thanks

Comment: You could try an sum-annotation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Calculate the Sum of the column values through query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616343/django-calculate-the-sum-of-the-column-values-through-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the db handle this by using [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total = transactions.aggregate(s=Sum("amount"))["s"]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) for doing that:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

transactions.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
# returns {'amount__sum': 1000} for example
```