# Is it possible for Django to sum lengths of a non-numeric field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have learned we can sum all(or filtered) columns like `price` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8616343/10844937).

```
ItemPrice.objects.aggregate(Sum('price'))
```

But is it possible for Django to sum non-numeric field's **length**, such as `CharField` or `JSONField`? A pseudocode is like following.

```
User.objects.aggregate(Sum(len('username')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length
from django.db.models import Sum
User.objects.annotate(l=Length("username")).aggregate(Sum("l"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try use

`from django.db.models.functions import Length User.objects.aggregate(Sum(Length('username')))`

Answer (score 0):

For a JSONFied, we can use `Count` to sum all the items.

```py
from django.db.models import Sum, Count
User.objects.annotate(l=Count("json_filed")).aggregate(Sum("l"))
```